# B2 visa extension due to covid

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, covid-19, visa-extensions

My mother's I-94 expires in April 23, 2020. We are in the process of filing I-539.

- Does it matter if we file online or paper form, our worry is the receipt as if we file the paper form we may not get the receipt number in time.
- What documents do we need to submit along with the application ?
- Will affidavit of support I 134 hurt or be useful ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you [file your I-539 online](https://www.uscis.gov/i539online), you will get an acknowledgement of receipt immediately upon completing the submission. If you file by paper, you can include [form G-1145](https://www.uscis.gov/g-1145) to request an email or text message when USCIS accepts your form.

If you file online you should be prompted for the [documents you need to include](https://www.uscis.gov/i-539Checklist). But in general you need:

- A copy of your I-94 form (you can [download a copy](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/) and print it)
- For extending B status, a written statement of explanation as to why you need to extend your stay

Form I-134 does not apply to your case. It is only used in cases where someone has been refused a visa on public charge grounds. You should not attempt to file this form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The document needed is statement, does it matter if I write on behalf of my mother or she has to write or can we both write. Any idea about that ?

Comment: @samy You can write it. There is a section on the I-539 form where you will enter your own name and details as the "Preparer" if you are actually filing it for your mother and she is not doing it herself.